# Buld Errors because of weblogic

Tags: ant, build, weblogic

I have the following code in my build.properties file

```
### WebLogic ###
bea.home=${tool.home}/bea

# weblogic 8.1: Change weblogic.home

weblogic.home=${bea.home}/weblogic81

#weblogic.home=${bea.home}/weblogic92

#weblogic.home=${bea.home}/wlserver_10.3

weblogic.version=8.1

ejb.spec.version=3.0
```

But after running the tools.build file it is showing the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
t:\DevEnv\3.1RC25\toolsetup.xml:22: 
The following error occurred while executing this line:
t:\DevEnv\3.1RC25\toolsetup.xml:184: Property 'weblogic.8.1.root' is not defined.
```

I have checked and the weblogic is in the folder T:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib

Is this a problem regarding the wrong versions of weblogic as I have weblogic81 on my machine?

Comment: This sounds like you just have a bad value in your `toolsetup.xml`. You likely should be referencing `weblogic.home` not `weblogic.8.1.root`

Comment: yeah that was the problem i tried it and its fixed